# Macbook Air Touchpad

Tags: mouse, touchpad, mac, multi-touch, macbook-air

I just installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my macbook air. Everything is working great except for one thing. The touchpad behaves slightly different than what it does on the Macbook.

In OSX I can move the mouse event though another finger is touching the surface. IE. if one finger is still and another moves, the mouse moves as normal. This is not the case in ubuntu. The mouse stops moving as soon as the second finger touches the touchpad. This is very annoying because part of my palm or left thumb regularly hits it by accident, stopping the mouse-movement. Not a big issue, but if I could get rid of it, that would be great. Normal 2-finger-scroll works the same way it does on my mac, so it's not because multi-touch isn't working, it seems.

Thanks alot in advance
-Viktor

Comment: You cannot move the mouse with more than one point of contact on the touch pad. This was a design decision made in the xInput layer. I am about to head off so don't have time to further explain but I will post up a few links in the morning.

Comment: Cool, I appreciate that :) Do you think that it is something that cam be modified in any way?

Comment: I prefer 12.10 for air... Because what I have show on 13.04... There are too much bugs regarding hardware ... Hope 12.10 will solve ur problem...

Comment: Hi, I'm having this problem too. Let's hope we can find an answer, this is still the case in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: yes, it is extremely annoying. I have reverted to OSX until some fix/hack is available

Comment: @mdoran3844 I know it's been a couple of years, but I'd still love to get those links you mentioned. :)

Answer (score 1):

Installing the [x86-input-mtrack driver](https://github.com/p2rkw/xf86-input-mtrack) makes the trackpad on my 2012 MacBook Air (Ubuntu 14.04) just as usable as under OS X. It supports resting the thumb/palm on the trackpad while using it, and 3/4-finger swipe gestures.

Comment: Could you provide a brief guide to install the suggested driver? Doing this will improve your answer.

Comment: There are some installation instructions on the github-page. I will try this out next time I run linux on a macbook (I switched to another machine)