# Macbook air 2008 rightclick with trackpad

Tags: touchpad, macbook

The question [Macbook Air Touchpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/340318/macbook-air-touchpad) did not solve my issue, after trying the answer there

---

I have a 2008 macbook air running Xubuntu 16.04 LTS. I somehow got my trackpad's right-click working with my newer Macbook pro, but the Macbook air has the older trackpad model, which has a touch field on top, and a clicking bar on the bottom.

Is there anyway to right-click when the right side of the clicking bar is pressed? If there is no way to do so, is it possible to at least <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> click to right-click?